# Как определить разрядность целого числа используя побитовый сдвиг на языке Си?

Tags: c++, c

Необходимо определить разрядность целого числа используя побитовый сдвиг, возможно использование побитовых операций, без использования for, while, библиотеки bitset. Система счисления 16-ая.
Разрядность - то есть количество числовых разрядов, необходимых для записи этого числа в той или иной системе счисления.

Comment: А что такое разрядность? Позиция старшей единички? Или максимальная вместимость выбранного типа данных? Если первое, то без циклов это невозможно.

Comment: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious

Comment: @maestro простыню из if можно сделать)

Comment: `unsigned a=0;` `cout << sizeof(a) * 8;` выведет общее количество бит, в которых хранится число 0.

Comment: @maestro, очевидно, что используется другая [разрядность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: @maestro сказали же, побитовый сдвиг : `sizeof(int) << 3`

Comment: Система счисления произвольная? Или некоторая конкретная? Как я понимаю, в столь неопределенной форме вопрос сейчас будет закрыт, так что если хотите что-то получить — сформулируйте его точно и однозначно для переоткрытия. Потому что вопрос может быть интересный, но он плохо сформулирован.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если именно шестнадцатеричная, без циклов и со сдвигом...

```
int digits16(unsigned long long n, int res = 0)
{
    if (n == 0) return res;
    return digits16(n >> 4, res + 1);
}
```

Годится? Правда, для нуля вернет ноль, но тут надо разобраться в условии задания, что именно надо вернуть для нуля — нуль или один...

```
int digits16(unsigned long long n, int res = 0)
{
    return n == 0 ? res : digits16(n >> 4, res + 1);
}
```

Comment: А есть ли способ обойтись и без IF?

Comment: Годится, как в ответе?